# The values of struct members are hidden when debugging in VS2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I define a list as:

```
typedef struct LinkNode LinkNode;
struct LinkNode {
     int value;
     LinkNode *next;
};
```

And I use this LinkNode type in main():

```
int main()
{
    LinkNode *p;
    ...
}
```

When I do single-step debugging in VS2010, sometimes the debugger shows the local variable p's value as 0xcccccccc{value = ??? next = ???}, but what I confuse is in some cases the value of p->value and p->next are hidden in debugging, p's value shows as Oxcccccccc. (the membership's values are invisible)

I don't know what is the mechanism behind these representations. I just test two projects with almost the same code (different variable name but the same data structures) and the result is as above. So what's the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: The value `0xcccccccc` is typical of uninitialized memory in the Visual Studio debugger. The debugger can't show what the members are because the pointer is not initialized.

Comment: I agree, but whether the pointer is uninitialized or allocated, the members are still not shown in the local variable window.

Comment: Do you have Optimization enabled in the project's C/C++ properties?

Answer (score 2):

`LinkNode *p` is an uninitialized pointer. You have to construct the object first, is like write `int* a` and try to see what `a` point to.
You have to write something like:

```
struct LinkNode {
     LinkNode(int value = int(), LinkNode* next = nullptr) :
               value(val), next(next)
     {
     }

     int value;
     LinkNode *next;
};

int main()
{
    LinkNode* p = new LinkNode();
    ...
    delete p;
}
```

**EDIT**
In c you have to use malloc and free... new and delete are not allowed.

```
typedef struct LinkNodeTag {         
     int value;
     struct LinkNodeTag *next;
} LinkNode;

LinkNode a = malloc(...);
free(a);
```

Unfortunatly I don't remember how malloc and free work...